Cold water in bathroom sink
The cold water from sink faucet in our bathroom smells like sewage. It is not coming from the drain. It is only that one faucet that is affected. No problem with the tub or toilet, or in the kitchen. We are on city water.
I'm at my wits end.

how do you know it is not the drain

I have disinterested the drain. I have also filled glasses of water and smelled them. If we let the water long enough the smell goes away. If we turn it on ten minutes later it stinks again.

Meant disinfected

what is the faucet type ? is it only with cold or hot water ? Any deposits in a glas of water after standing for a hour

Do you have a cold-water tank in your loft for the hot-water system? If so, it's possible something has died in it, and your water for the bathroom is connected to that, rather than mains water.

Faucet type I guess I'd call a regular 2 handle. Hot on left, cold on right. No deposits. It is only the cold. There is no cold water tank.

If something had died in a cold water tank wouldn't the same smell come through the cold water in the tub?

With only the cold water at the sink, the problem should be local from the faucet to the cold water tee the sink comes off from.  Might be some pipe scum or one section of the pipe is made with a different material than others.

Definitely check with you local water utility. Some reservoirs, for example, experience an algal bloom in summer, which may be harmless but result in water that tastes and smells "fishy".
The usual solution for safe-but-unpleasant water is to buy a filtered pitcher or tank, or to install and maintain in-line filters, to remove what got past the water service's processing.

No problem with the tub or toilet, or in the kitchen

Some things I would try:
Remove the aerator from the faucet and clean or replace it.
If it really is just the cold side of the faucet, shut off water and disconnect the line from the faucet. Then turn the water back on and fill a clean cup or bucket from the cold side. Does it still smell? If so, you’ve eliminated the faucet itself. If not, then it’s the faucet. Remove it and deep clean and replace the seals or replace it.
If it’s not the faucet, then try running the cold line into a bucket for a while to flush it out.
If that doesn’t help, you may want to call a plumber to trace the line back.
